# Introductory book about economic models with deterministic chaos

Tags: economics, chaos-theory

I'm looking for introductory textbook about economic models (micro/macro/finance) which incorporate deterministic chaos. Models could be with or without random noise. By introductory I meant master level textbook. Is it better stackexchange site to ask this question ?

Comment: chaos was in fashion during the 80's, no really interesting models with chaos survived in economics